# Replaying MVC actions from history

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, object

Im building an ASP.NET MVC app which has lots of pages that allow users to request different automatic 'workflows' to be submitted. The user selects a flow, fills in a form and hits submit. When the model gets POSTed back into MVC, my code copies the model data into a 'Flow' object which is then sent to the flow request service.

The Flow object contains a dictionary named InputMap which maps the input names that the workflow service expects to the model's properties.

My request service is invoked in the controller - the request service accepts the flow object from the model, sends it to the workflow infrastructure, then serializes the flow object and stores it in the db. I want the user to be able to re-request the workflow, by deserializing the persisted flow object and re-filling the view.

Im doing the flow **update** and **reheat** with two methods on my model, like so:

```
namespace AutomationForms.Models
{
    public class FileTransfer
    {
        public string RequestNumber { set; get; }
        public string HostName { set; get; }
        public string CurrentPartner { get; set; }
        public string PartnerSearch { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<String,Flow> Flows { get; set; }

        public FileTransfer()
        {
            Flows = new Dictionary<String, Flow>();
            Update();
        }

        public void Update(){

            //CFT_Install Flow
            var cftInstall = new Flow("CFT Install");
            cftInstall.InputMap["hostname"] = HostName ?? "";
            cftInstall.InputMap["partner"] = CurrentPartner ?? "";

            Flows[cftInstall.Name] = cftInstall;

            //CFT_Update Flow
            var cftUpdate = new Flow("CFT Update");
            cftUpdate.InputMap["snRequestId"] = RequestNumber ?? "";
            cftUpdate.InputMap["partner_search"] = PartnerSearch ?? "";

            Flows[cftUpdate.Name] = cftUpdate;
        }

        public void Reheat(Flow flow)
        {
            HostName = flow.InputMap["hostname"] ?? "";
            CurrentPartner = flow.InputMap["partner"] ?? "";
            RequestNumber = flow.InputMap["snRequestId"] ?? "";
            PartnerSearch = flow.InputMap["partner_search"] ?? "";
        }
    }

}
```

I can tell this isn't idomatic MVC and/or is bad OO design - I feel like there must be an easier way to 'two-way bind' the flow and the model properties together automatically, so I can:-

1. keep the model and its flow objects updated automatically;
2. automatically 'reheat' an old flow object & refill the view.

Please can anyone help me work out the way in which I am thinking about this wrong?